# Adding support for menuconfig / Kconfig in my project

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I am planning to add support for menuconfig in my project. The project is not associated with Linux kernel so, I have to write everything from scratch in menuconfig and Makefile.

How do I add support for menuconfig and create Kconfig and make the makefile read the defines in .config?

Any good tutorial to begin with?

Comment: Good point to start is U-Boot sources. They migrated to kernel build system recently, so it's good reference for how to do that. You can start with `git log -- scripts/kconfig/` in U-Boot sources dir to investigate the process.

Comment: I have same question as yours. Can you let everyone know what you eventually did?

Comment: @user435739 were you able to find a solution for this? I need to do the same for cortex-M microcontroller based projects, so nothing to do with Linux. If you were able to add the menuconfig to your project please share.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested on using KBuild/KConfig for your custom applications, you may try the following Github projects. They aim to provide an initial template for projects using KBuild/KConfig and, therefore, supporting menuconfig.

- Kbuild skeleton: https://github.com/masahir0y/kbuild_skeleton
- Kbuild template: https://github.com/embedded-it/kbuild-template

Answer (score 0):

First you need to copy the folders and files below from linux folder ['scripts'](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/scripts) into your own project

- basic
- kconfig
- Kbuild.include
- Makefile.build
- Makefile.host
- Makefile.lib

Sources in folders basic and kconfig need to be built for your processor architecture. How to do it is written in the linux [Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile). You can change some names using next variables

- KCONFIG_CONFIG = .config
- KCONFIG_AUTOHEADER = application/autoconf.h
- KCONFIG_AUTOCONFIG = build/include/config/auto.conf
- KCONFIG_TRISTATE = build/include/config/tristate.conf

The following project initially created for ARM MCUs can help you to understand kconfig

https://github.com/mcu/kconfig

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume you are making a driver that is outside of the kernel directory.   Information for that can be found here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt.

Outside of that, if you want a userspace file to see the .config variables, you can have it depend on the kernel build, and then include autoconf.h, which is in the include/generated folder for recent versions of the kernel.  Userspace does not use kbuild directly.