# Using 'make menuconfig' / Kconfig infrastructure for my project

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I'd like to take advantage of the existing 'make menuconfig' / Kconfig infrastructure to build a configuration file for my own project, which has nothing to do with Linux kernel or module development. I mostly develop on Linux.

Where can I get the code ? Is there an API to read the configuration file created by make menuconfig ? Last question (although I think I know the answer) : will it run on Windows ?

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841101/adding-support-for-menuconfig-kconfig-in-my-project

Answer (score 0):

The code is available in a separate repository here: http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/git/kconfig-frontends/tree/ but it is lagging a bit behind what's in the kernel (v4.8 instead of v4.9).

Regarding the API, it generates an include file with the defined symbols (by default `include/generated/autoconf.h`). You simply include that file from the code that needs to be configured.

It can probably be made to run on Windows. I'd say cygwin may help but it may not even be necessary.